# how to enable jquery in ajax page navigation using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am building a web app and for the mobile version, I am using jquery mobile.
Everything is fine except when I use the ajax default navigation, the new page doesnt respond to the javascript, in fact, using chrome's dev mode, I found out that despite being active, all the jquery was happening in the prior page. I am thinking of building my custom navigation to fix it but if someone knows how to handle the jquery mobile thing first I will appreciate.

ps: The links are dynamics so same ids and classes between pages

Comment: AJAX navigation loads the first data=role="Page" div from the linked page.  Therefore any needed javascript needs to be within that DIV or already included in the parent page.  Also as pages stay in the DOM, you might be having issues with non-unique IDs as more pages are loaded...

Comment: Well, I found a trick that seems to be working with all browsers I tested (chrome, mozilla, safari and ie). 
I will post an answer and an explanation on why i needed it that way